# When a $C^*$-algebra is an ideal in its second dual?

Tags: oa.operator-algebras, c-star-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

I would like to know which $C^*$-algebras are ideals in their second duals?

There is a [paper by S. Watanabe](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.nihmj/1273778977) that claims in introduction that it is well known that a $C^*$-algebra is an ideal in its second dual iff it is a dual $C^*$-algebra. But I do not know what does he mean by term "dual $C^*$-algebra".

For the general case of normed algebras there is a criterion (see Banach algebras and the general theory of *-algebras. Volume I. Algebras and Banch algebras. Theodore W. Palmer, theorem 1.4.13): $A$ is a two-sided ideal in $A^{**}$ iff the maps $L_a:A\to A$, $b\mapsto ab$ and $R_a:A\to A$, $b\mapsto ab$ are weakly compact for all $a\in A$.

May be this criterion could be improved for the case of $C^*$-algebras. You may even assume that $A$ is commutative.

Comment: What about examples such as $c_0$ or $K(H)$?

Comment: I think that for any unital Banach algebra $A$ the natural embedding $A\to A^{**}$ is a unital homomorphism (for both Arens products). It follows that $A$ cannot be an ideal in $A^{**}$ unless $A$ is reflexive as a Banach space.

Comment: @YemonChoi, thank you. I'll edit my question.

Comment: It is "well-known" but he doesn't give a reference? Hmm ...

Comment: @NikWeaver TBF I have been known to use "well-known" when I can't locate a precise reference, or where the reference I have seen a certain claim is clearly not the originator of the result

Comment: Regarding the terminology "dual $C^\ast$-algebra" -- I think that in some older works on Banach algebras, such as Bonsall and Duncan's book, the term "dual (Banach) algebra" had a different meaning from its present usage. Looking in my copy of B+D, it appears that the usage goes back to a 1948 paper of Kaplansky titled "Dual rings"

Comment: Having done some quick foraging online: there is a short 1975 paper of Ylinen that should be relevant, "Weakly completely continuous elements of $C^\ast$-algebras". I'll try to come back to it later when I have time

Comment: I don't understand the 1st two comments of @YemonChoi: "...unless $A$ is reflexive as a Banach space" seems to contradict the examples like $c_0$ and $K(H)$.  Is the phrase "dual Banach algebra" missing?  As later noted, this is very different to being a "dual $C^\ast$-algebra".

Comment: @MatthewDaws: The second of Yemon Choi's comments only refers to unital algebras.

Comment: @JochenGlueck: Ah, of course!!  I had somehow failed to see "unital".

Comment: @MatthewDaws It's OK, I haven't suddenly gained the impression that $c_0=\ell_\infty$ ... :D

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Warning: the following is just what I found from some work on MathSciNet, following Yemon's hint in the comments.  It's not meant to be accurate historical notes.

A "dual" $C^\ast$-algebra is defined as follows.  Let $A$ be an algebra and for a subset $M\subseteq A$ let $R(M) = \{ x\in A : Mx=\{0\}\}$; similarly define $L(M) = \{ x\in A : xM=\{0\}\}$.  Then a $C^\ast$-algebra is *dual* if for each closed left ideal $I$ we have that $L(R(I))=I$.  (The involution can be used to show that the analogous definition with right ideals gives the same notion).

An early paper which studied these is [Kaplansky, The structure of certain operator algebras](https://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1951-070-02/S0002-9947-1951-0042066-0/), see section 2.  It seems that [Berglund, Ideal $C^\ast$-algebras](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.dmj/1077309715) was the first to obtain the equivalence you seek (why is the Duke journal archive behind a paywall??)  A short proof is in [McCharen, A characterization of dual $B^{\ast}$-algebras](https://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1973-037-01/S0002-9939-1973-0306927-7/)  These give the following:

**Claim:** A $C^\ast$-algebra $A$ is an ideal in its bidual if and only if $A$ is dual.

We now combine this with known characterisations of dual $C^\ast$-algebras:

**Claim:** A $C^\ast$-algebra $A$ is dual if and only if $A$ is isomorphic to a $C^\ast$-subalgebra of $K(H)$ for some $H$ if and only if $A$ is the $c_0$-direct sum of algebras of the form $K(H)$ for some (finite or infinite dimensional) $H$.

Thus $K(H)$ and $c_0$ really are the archetypal examples.  These results are quoted in the paper of Kaplansky I linked above, and in Dixmier's book (English edition, section 4.7.20) though in both cases it seems only further references are given, not proofs.  I am afraid that I don't know of a modern, self-contained treatment.

Comment: Here is an interesting example of how "well-known" is a dangerous phrase!  Back in the day, such results probably were very well-known, when everyone knew lots about liminal $C^\ast$-algebras.  45+ years later, we still want to read the papers, but the people reading the papers are a new generation, and that folk knowledge has disappeared...

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: It feels like there should be a more direct way to see that the assumption that each left and right multiplication operator on $A$ is weakly compact (Ylinen's condition) forces $A$ to somehow be generated by projections $p$ such that $pA$ is finite-dimensional ... but I admit I don't see right now how to construct a proof.